# How should I handle multithreading in MVVM c# apps

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, uwp

As I understand my app should run on single thread (UI thread), and there are 2 cases, where I may want to execute code on another thread:

1. there is long running job, like system/db access and so on

   - such code should use async/await
   - when execution gets to actual file access, the library handling it should have use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, which will schedule continuation on another thread from threadpool
   - then some other await in app code (without `.ConfigureAwait(false)`) will resume on UI thread
2. there are asynchronous notifications from other threads (system, devices etc.)

   - these should be scheduled on UI thread using dispatcher
3. Additional assumptions:

   - model should isolate multithreading
   - there should be no dispatcher calls in viewmodels

Is this summary correct?

Comment: Could you please share some code examples?

Comment: Doesn't sound totally wrong, but whether it's "correct" or not is partly opinion-based.

Comment: Why no dispatcher calls in the view model?  Just wondering as I tend to end up getting events from services that are not on the UI thread and I need to use the dispatcher to get back on the UI thread so I can update some data bound property.  Is that not the correct way to do that?

Comment: @RobGoodwin my theory is that one should encapsulate these service calls in model, and model should care about dispatching them on UI thread. From my experience one event in model can update lots of UI properties, so if you do not lock vm to UI thread you need dispatch calls everywhere.

Comment: @Shadow I always feel weird when doing something in the model for the view.  For example, we have a large codebase, where the model classes are in a separate assembly.  This assembly is used by many applications, both in user interface based applications, and some server side headless apps.  On those headless services, I would not want to have any code that dictates what threads property updates get generated on.  To me, that job would reside in the view model. But that is just my opinion, and I am by no means a pattern purest.

Comment: @Shadow: For the most part that looks good. For (2), I prefer using `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Dispatcher` since the former doesn't tie you to a specific UI framework.

Comment: @RobGoodwin maybe there is no single best solution? Your approach is the one which I have in app now, and I dislike added complexity in ViewModel, however if I had shared backend probably it would make sense. On the other hand if I was just doing small app I think it would be easier to isolate third party updates, rather than everything in ViewModel.

Comment: @StephenCleary You mean SynchronizationContext.Current.Send/Post?

Comment: @Shadow I mean capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and then later call `Send`/`Post`.